# Ember-cli throwing Unexpected Token error

Tags: ember.js, firebase, ember-cli, emberfire

Undoubtedly this error is something easy for an ember expert to identify but thats not me so here it is

Ember-cli identifies blank space before this line as an unexpected token:
this.store = container.lookup('store:main');

```
/*global md5*/
import Ember from 'ember';

// Since I've defined my url in environment.js I can do this
import ENV from '../config/environment';
var ref = new window.Firebase(ENV.firebaseURL);

export default {
    name: 'session',

    // Run the initializer after the store is ready
    after: 'store',

    initialize: function(container, app) {  
        // session object is nested here as we need access to the container to get the store
        var session = Ember.Object.extend({

            // initial state
            authed: false,

            // get access to the ember data store

//Here is the offending line
this.store = container.lookup('store:main');


            init: function() {

                // on init try to login
                ref.onAuth(function(authData) {

                    // Not authenticated
                    if (!authData) {
                        this.set('authed', false);
                        this.set('authData', null);
                        this.set('user', null);
                        return false;
                    }

                    // Authenticated
                    this.set('authed', true);
                    this.set('authData', authData);
                    this.afterAuthentication(authData.uid);
                }.bind(this));
            },

            // Call this from your Ember templates
            login: function(provider) {
                this._loginWithPopup(provider);
            },

            // Call this from your Ember templates
            logout: function() {
                ref.unauth();
            },

            // Default login method
            _loginWithPopup: function(provider) {
                var _this = this;
                // Ember.debug('logging in with popup');
                ref.authWithOAuthPopup(provider, function(error, authData) {
                    if (error) {
                        if (error.code === "TRANSPORT_UNAVAILABLE") {
                            // fall-back to browser redirects, and pick up the session
                            // automatically when we come back to the origin page
                            _this._loginWithRedirect(provider);
                        }
                    } else if (authData) {
                        // we're good!
                        // this will automatically call the on ref.onAuth method inside init()
                    }
                });
            },

            // Alternative login with redirect (needed for Chrome on iOS)
            _loginWithRedirect: function(provider) {
                ref.authWithOAuthRedirect(provider, function(error, authData) {
                    if (error) {

                    } else if (authData) {
                        // we're good!
                        // this will automatically call the on ref.onAuth method inside init()
                    }
                });
            },

            // Runs after authentication
            // It either sets a new or already exisiting user
            afterAuthentication: function(userId) {
                var _this = this;

                // See if the user exists using native Firebase because of EmberFire problem with "id already in use"
                ref.child('users').child(userId).once('value', function(snapshot) {
                    var exists = (snapshot.val() !== null);
                    userExistsCallback(userId, exists);
                });

                // Do the right thing depending on whether the user exists
                function userExistsCallback(userId, exists) {
                    if (exists) {
                        _this.existingUser(userId);
                    } else {
                        _this.createUser(userId);
                    }
                }
            },

            // Existing user
            existingUser: function(userId) {
                this.store.find('user', userId).then(function(user) {
                    _this.set('user', user);
                }.bind(this));
            },

            // Create a new user
            createUser: function(userId) {
                var _this = this;

                this.get('store').createRecord('user', {
                    id: userId,
                    provider: this.get('authData.provider'),
                    name: this.get('authData.facebook.displayName') || this.get('authData.google.displayName'),
                    email: this.get('authData.facebook.email') || this.get('authData.google.email'),
                    created: new Date().getTime()
                }).save().then(function(user){

                    // Proceed with the newly create user
                    _this.set('user', user);
                });
            },

            // This is the last step in a successful authentication
            // Set the user (either new or existing)
            afterUser: function(user) { 
                this.set('user', user);
            }
        });

        // Register and inject the 'session' initializer into all controllers and routes
        app.register('session:main', session);
        app.inject('route', 'session', 'session:main');
        app.inject('controller', 'session', 'session:main');
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling `Ember.Object.extend` with an [Javascript Object literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Object_literals) what you are trying to do is invalid javascript syntax.

You'll probably want to stick that line in your `init` function.

```
init: function() {
  //Here is the offending line
  this.store = container.lookup('store:main');

  ...
```

When you get an invalid token error message you're writing something the javascript compiler doesn't understand.

Comment: You're welcome. You can mark the answer as the corrext one by clicking on the checkmark :)